# Datepick window opens under different input field

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using **jquery.datepick.js** library for making date input fields. I have a section where users can duplicate multiple divs. When I have just one div and date fields inside, the date window shows under each input and it is correct. However, when I have multiple date fields, this date window is showing under first divs date inputs, not pressed ones (like in the [video](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1bf8FIABB4rNCPlbFe6mRvn6ryioUoXCq)). What can be wrong? How to make date windows show under each field?

Here is the HTML code:

```
<input id="scheduleList[0][ticketPriceList][1][ticketStartDate]" class="by-date is-datepick" type="text" name="scheduleList[0][ticketPriceList][1][ticketStartDate]" value="17.05.2020" placeholder="DD.MM.YYYY" autocomplete="off">
```

And here is JS:

```
    <script src="/template/js/jquery.plugin.js"></script>
    <script src="/template/js/jquery.datepick.js"></script>
    <link href="/template/css/smoothness.datepick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script>
        $('.by-date').datepick({
            dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
            rangeSelect: false,
            monthsToShow: 1,
            showAnim: '',
            minDate: 0,
            showTrigger: '.by-date-icon'
        });

        $(document).on('focus', '.by-date', function () {
            $(this).next().next().find('i').addClass('active')
        })
        $(document).on('blur', '.by-date', function () {
            $(this).next().next().find('i').removeClass('active')
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: Show us your  "multiple date fields" HTML markup. I see only one so there is no way to replicate the problem. Your one input HTML code will not help us at all. [mre]

Comment: Other ones look like this:


`<input id="scheduleList[0][ticketPriceList][2][ticketStartDate]" class="by-date is-datepick" type="text" name="scheduleList[0][ticketPriceList][1][ticketStartDate]" value="17.05.2020" placeholder="DD.MM.YYYY" autocomplete="off">`


Just changes name and ID of input. 

`<input id="scheduleList[0][ticketPriceList][3][ticketStartDate]" class="by-date is-datepick" type="text" name="scheduleList[0][ticketPriceList][1][ticketStartDate]" value="17.05.2020" placeholder="DD.MM.YYYY" autocomplete="off">`